# Unchecking radio-boxes in a pdf with restricted security

Tags: pdf, acrobat

I just finished filling out a mammoth 100+ page background check in a .pdf file. I reviewed it and found I had mistakenly checked a few radio boxes, but I cannot uncheck them. How can I uncheck these boxes? The document is password-protected so I don't have the ability to edit the document or script. Is there any way to uncheck the boxes or should I go through the hassle of filling it out all over again?

I'm using Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro.

Comment: And you're doing this with what programming language? This site is specifically for programming related questions. You're likely to get better answers on something like an Adobe forum about Acrobat for example.

Comment: Can we migrate this to superuser?

Answer (score 5):

There *is* a way! But only if you haven't saved the document already. Right after you fill or check a box you didn't intend to, type Ctrl-Z. That's it!

Comment: Worked after I saved, but not closed, the document

Comment: Worked for me too. Saved but still open. Not sure what security level was on the document. I think it only reset the button focused, but it 'may' have been the last change I made.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the *"Clear Form"* option under *"Forms"* in the menu bar. My guess is that's your only option. (But then, you may need to fill out the complete mammoth 100+ page PDF once again...)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Preview on MacOS, you can revert to an earlier version of the document where the boxes had not been checked: `File`->`Revert To`.